# How to know whether I have admin authority in windows？

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authority

Is there any APIs in windows to detect whether the current user(current now) has the admin authority?

BOOL IsHasAuthority（）
{
}

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[How to Determine Whether a Process or Thread Is Running As an Administrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff420334.aspx)

> Use this solution when you are writing
>   an application that must determine
>   whether any of the following is true:
>
> - The current user can perform    administrative tasks. The current
>     user is a member of the
> - Administrators group. A supplied    token handle represents an
>     administrator with an elevated token.
> - A token handle represents a user who    is a member of the
>     Administrators    group.
> - The program is running with an    elevated token or needs to spawn a
>     child program that is elevated so it
>     can perform administrative tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows API function [`CheckTokenMembership()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(VS.85).aspx).  The MSDN documentation for that function has an example demonstrating how to check for membership in the Administrators local group.

Comment: The docs for [IsUserAnAdmin()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463.aspx) redirect to that page as well.

Comment: @MSalters:  Oh... I didn't know there was such a function.  Cool.